# Bayes problem with multiple testing

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

**Question**: One in one hundred and forty people have a particular disease. A diagnosis test gives a false positive 2 % of the time, and a false negative 8% of the time.
We took 3 tests **simultaneously** and got 1 negative and 2 positive tests.

1. What is the probability that we have disease?
2. What will be the probability if we took 3 sequent tests: a) one negative first and 2 positives after? b) vice versa?

I think I nanaged to solve 1st part of task with simultaneously testing:

A - we have disease
B - positive test
C - negative test
D - 1 negative and 2 positive tests

P(A/D) = P(D/A) * P(A) / P(D)
P(D) = 1/140 * 92% * 92% * 8% + 139/140 * 98% * 2% * 2% = 0.09%
P(D/A) = 92% * 92% * 8% = 6.8%
P(A/D) = 6,8% * 1/140 / 0,09% = 55.6% - the answer on 1st question

Is it correct? I don't understand how to solve part with **sequent** testing.

Comment: Note:  there are some (critical) missing assumptions here.  Are we to imagine that the errors occur *independently*?  That's a very strong, and very unrealistic, assumption. In reality, false test results might reflect alternate pathologies or idiosyncracies in the patient changing the probabilities for subsequent tests.

Comment: In any case, once you have used the given information to revise your probabilities, you'll have a probability $p$ that the patient has the disease (N.B. I did it hastily and got $p=.554$ which resembles but doesn't exactly match your result.).  Once you have that, then the probability of getting the desired next round of results is $p\times .08\times .92^2+(1-p)\times .98\times 02^2$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why we take p=0,554 for calculating probability of sequent tests?

Comment: As I say, I did it hastily so I might have made an arithmetic error.  If he has the disease, we'll see these results with probability $a=3\times .08\times .92^2$.  If he doesn't have it, we'll get these results with probability $b=3\times .98\times .02^2$.  Thus the numerator of the desired probability is $\frac 1{140}\times a$ and the denominator is that plus $\frac {139}{140}\times b$.  That gives $0.55410802$.  As I say, it's close to what you got so arithmetic might explain the difference.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the second question of the task. The probality of .554 answers about 3 simultaneous tests. But what to do with sequent testing (second question)?

Comment: Again, you seem to have obtained $.556$, and that's a big enough difference that it ought to be resolved.  Sticking with $p=.554$ for now...what's the problem?  If I want $NPP$ in that order then we just have two scenarios (according to whether or not the patient has the disease).  These are mutually exclusive so we can just add the probabilities.  Note that changing the order doesn't change the probability.